# Rspec Rails error : same route name, different verb

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm actually experiencing a weird behavior when testing my controller. I have a `UsersController` that have 2 methods, `me` and `update_me` :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def me
    # some code
  end

  def update_me
    # some code
  end
end
```

and the corrsponding routes are :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get :me, to: 'users#me'
  patch :me, to: 'users#update_me'
end
```

When testing `GET /me`, everything works fine and all tests pass :

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController do
  describe '#me' do
    it 'respond with a 200 ok status' do
      get :me, format: :json, access_token: user_token.token
      expect(response.status).to eq 200
    end

    # more tests
  end
end
```

but when I'm trying to make a patch request to me :

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController do
  describe '#update_me' do
    it 'respond with a 200 ok status' do
      patch :me, format: :json, user: attributes, access_token: user_token.token
      expect(response.status).to eq 200
    end

    # more tests
  end
end
```

RSpec is actually showing me an error on line 17 in `UsersController`, which is actually the line related to the `def me` method, where it should actually be `def update_me`.

So I put a `raise` within `update_me` and realized that this method was never actually called by RSpec. However, when testing a real case scenario using Postman, everything works fine, I can `get` and `patch` a user correctly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get` and `patch` methods don't take a route as the first argument, they take the name of the action within the controller you are testing. You're invoking the `me` method in your `patch` call as well, which is why it goes there. See the [RSpec controller test documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs) and the underlying [Rails controller test documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-patch) for details.